# Left Join two tables with one common column and other diff columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables where main table has 10+ columns and second table has 3 columns with one common field. My problem here is I am not able to get exact count with left outer join as main table. I am seeing more count than actual. It might be due to one of the field I am trying to get is not in main table which is in second table.

- Table 1: master_table
- Table 2: manager_table

Master_table :

- ID,
- Column1,
- Column2,
- ...
- Column10

manager_table:

- ID,
- Column2_different,
- Column3_different

I am trying to join using `Left Join` to get same records as present in master table.

```
Select table1.columns, table2.columns
From table1
Left join table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
```

The above is not giving me exact record count as in master table (table1) , it is giving me more count as the table 2 other field is not present in table 1 .

Can someone help me here ?

TIA

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: If you have 1 record in your main table, but three columns in your second table that share that common field, then you will get 3 records back when you join them (regardless of join type). That's just how this works. Which one of the three would you want? Perhaps for the column in the second table you are after all three rows have the same value? In that case you would need to aggregate that second table in a subquery and then join it to your main table. To get a less generic answer, you'll have to share some sample data and desired results.

Comment: It is hard to follow your explanation. Obviously you join more than one manager row to a master table row. Please show a row from the master table, the rows you join to it from the manager table, the result rows you are getting and the result row you want to get. Explain why you want that single row and dismiss the others.

Comment: This table1/table2 thing makes it harder to understand the tables by the way. Why not simply call them master_table and manager_table throughout the request? Then, what ID are you actually joining the tables on? It is not likely that you join `ON master_table.id = manager_table.id`, because hopefully the master_table.id uniquely identifies a row in the master_table, while the manager_table.id uniquely identifies a row in the manager_table. Does your master_table contain a manager_table_id you use in the join or does the manager_table contain a master_table_id you use? Or something else still?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an `INNER JOIN` would be better than a `LEFT JOIN`. Need some sample data to be sure, but if you're getting a higher count than you'd expect upon joining the tables this is probably because the `LEFT JOIN` is returning everything from both tables. An `INNER JOIN` will only return data that appears in both tables.